# After changing one layer's projection, layers don't overlay correctly

Tags: coordinate-system, global-mapper

I have 2 raster layer in global mapper.
1 layer in WGS 84 and geographic coordinate system.(ALOSDEM)
The second one is in NAD83 UTM Zone.(SASPlanet Image)
Both of these layer are overlayed in global mapper because,as we knew global mapper have the function called "On the fly Projection".

But after i manually change Second layer Using Configure options the result is both of these layer is no longer overlayed.

Why did this happened ??[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When editing a layer, pay attention to the warnings. I get this one when attempting to change the projection

[image]

The warning is telling you that you are about to change the underlying data. You do not want to do that unless you know the projection was incorrect when the file was loaded.

Answer (score 2):

As you have already mentioned, Global Mapper (as well QGIS) has "On the fly projection". Sometimes this softwares automatically overlay diferrent rasters/shapes according to their projection system. This is, even if you have two different projections the software will do internally the changes.

I recommend you "reprojecting" the second. By doing this you will have both rasters in the same projection.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? If not, let me know and I can post some screenshots on how to do it.